# Cors error while redirecting to google auth api

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am getting cors error while redirecting to google auth api. I have implemented this using springboot.

[image: This is the preflight request]

[image: the failed request]

this request is being redirect from another google api: [image]

i have tried adding origin anf access control allow origin headers but non of them works.

[image: this is the configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I see you mentioned localhost as your redirect URL. You should mention the same redirect URL on your google console project.

Also, error 405 means the server doesn't know the method you are using. Please check the list of methods. as mentioned (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/405), The server must generate an Allow header field in a 405 status code response. The field must contain a list of methods that the target resource currently supports.

Best!
Makanist

Comment: i have used the same redirect url as mentioned on google console. secondly, the link you have mentioned is inaccessible. Also the 405 error is for options method. its just checking whether the origin and referer are same or not to access the api further. In my case, the origin is going null this the options method is failing and giving cors error

Comment: looks like that URL is gone.. weird!! In your google console you have the redirecting url mentioned? I don't know if you are using a desktop flow or webserver flow. You can follow instructions as per your desired work flow and use client library mentioned in OAuth2.0 guide https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server.

Comment: updated URL in my answer above.